# grunt-sass (with bower compass package) throwing error on compile

Tags: sass, gruntjs, compass-sass

I am trying out grunt-sass (instead of grunt-contrib-watch) to use the super speedy libsass compiler.

I've managed to get it working with compass by using a compass bower package. (https://github.com/Igosuki/compass-mixins) So the compass mixins are available. However I am getting the following error

```
error: only variable declarations and control directives are allowed inside functions
```

The error is pointing to an @if statement in one of my function calls (i've tried removing that function but it just then fails at the next @if statement).

If I omit my functions file I then get another error, pointing to one of my mixins

```
error: expected '{' in media query Use --force to continue.
```

Does anyone have any idea what's going on?

All of this stuff was working when using grunt-contrib-watch.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With no actual sass file to look at I assume that you are using features that aren't implemented in libsass yet. To quote from the [offical node-sass repo](https://github.com/andrew/node-sass#reporting-sass-compilation-and-syntax-issues) (on which grunt-sass) is based on:

> The libsass library is not currently at feature parity with the 3.2
>   Ruby Gem that most Sass users will use, and has little-to-no support
>   for 3.3 syntax. While we try our best to maintain feature parity with
>   libsass, we can not enable features that have not been implemented in
>   libsass yet.

Comment: That'll be why then.  I'm using sass 3.3. Thanks